# How did Balarama reach Yashoda's house in Vrindavana?

Tags: balarama, vrindavana

The story of Vasudev taking Krishna to Nand and Yashoda is well-known.

But how did Balarama, who was also Vasudev's son, *reach* Vrindavana?
And what happened to Rohini who carried him as a surrogate mother?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rohini and other wives of Vasudeva used to live at the home of Nanda Mahārāja due to fear of Kaṁsa:

> The Lord ordered Yoga-māyā:
>
> In that very beautiful land, where many cows reside, Rohiṇī, the wife of Vasudeva, is living at the home of Nanda Mahārāja. Other wives of Vasudeva are also living there incognito because of fear of Kaṁsa. Please go there.
>
> Within the womb of Devakī is My partial plenary expansion known as Saṅkarṣaṇa or Śeṣa. Without difficulty, transfer Him into the womb of Rohiṇī.
>
> ~ [Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam (Bhāgavata Purāṇa): Skandha 10: CHAPTER TWO](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/2/)

So, Balraama was born in Nanda/Yasoda's home as Rohini used to live there.

Comment: I don't understand it. How was Balram transferred from Devki to Rohini?

Comment: Yogmaya transferred him from Devaki's womb to Rohini' womb..if you r talking about it in practical/science then, it's off topic here..but in my view, it was something similar to "gestational surrogacy"..

Comment: what's Yogmaya? Can you please tell?

Comment: https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/yogamaya you can refer this link..she is a goddess..